# python break process if memory consumption is to high

Tags: python, ram, sigkill

I am using a module and sometimes it crashes, because of memory consumption. It is terminated by SIGKILL 9 and the script is interrupted. However I cannot access the loop in which the memory consumption happens.

This is how it looks now:

```
import module
output = module.function(args)
```

and this sort of how it should look like:

```
import module
if ramconsumption(module.function(args)) > 999:
     output = None
else:
     output = module.function(args)
```

Do you know a way on how to implement this? My example is just for better understanding, the solution should just be one where I do not get a SIGKILL, when too much memory is consumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work:

```py
import os
import psutil
import module
import threading

def checkMemory():
    while True:
        process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
        memoryUsage = process.memory_info().rss #in bytes
        if memoryUsage > amount:
            print("Memory budget exceeded")
            break
    os._exit(0)

threading.Thread(name="Memory Regulator", target=checkMemory).start()

output = module.function(args)
```

Comment: I suppose this would before or after my function. If so, this would be of no use, because this very function causes the problem and no loop around it or so

Comment: You could simply start it with a thread before calling your function, like so:
```threading.Thread(name="Memory Regulator", target=checkMemory()).start()```
This would cause the function to run continuously.